Is meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B-Instruct able to perform tools call with langchain/huggingface library?
I'm struggling to make meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B-Instruct calls my custom functions as tools.
From model documentation, it seems that meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B* models supports tools, but I'm not able to make it work.
I've tried to use langchain-huggingface (https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/providers/huggingface/), but I see that support for tools is not implemented.
Also trying with customized system prompts seems to not solve the problem. Models ignore tools.
Is there any advice on how to use a meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B* tiny model with tools calling?
Thanks!

Any model (even a fake/dummy one where the logit probabilities are completely random) can perform tool calls if you use a framework like LMQL or Guidance to force its output to follow the relevant paths in the decoding layer.
